# Sage's Reverie + Imprisoned in the Moon

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose you have [Imprisoned in the Moon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImprisoned%20in%20the%20Moon%5d) a creature (turning it into a land) and then cast [Sage's Reverie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSage%27s%5d%2b%5bReverie%5d). Would you draw a card for Imprisoned in the Moon? My assumption is no, since the enchanted creature is a land, not a creature, but I figured I should ask just in case I misinterpreted the rules.

Comment: @DavidAlves The OP never said they are targeting the permanent enchanted with Imprisoned in the Moon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. You do not get to draw a card for [Imprisoned in the Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=414360).

Your reasoning is also correct. You do not draw the card because the enchanted creature is not a creature anymore. Only the current card types count here.